# Find all possible routes, from root to leaf, on a tree that has multiple children per node.

Tags: c#, depth-first-search

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to find multiple routes, from a given station on the london underground. The project i'm having is the creation of routes. I have created a method with uses DFS and recursion. 
This method takes in the name of the starting station, an empty List and an integer value. When I execute the method using the following code:

```
GetRoutes("HOLBORN", list, 4);
```

I get the following results in my list

```
HOLBORN
CHANCERY LANE
ST PAULS
BANK
LIVERPOOL STREET
TOTTENHAM COURT ROAD
OXFORD CIRCUS
RUSSELL SQUARE
KINGS CROSS
COVENT GARDEN
```

The first strings in the list display a valid path:

```
HOLBORN => CHANCERY LANE => ST PAULS => BANK => LIVERPOOL STREET
```

However, I then need it to search again for alternate routes like:

```
HOLBORN => CHANCERY LANE => ST PAULS => BANK => LONDON BRIDGE
```

Here is questionable method:

```
    public List<string> GetRoutes(string stationName, List<string> completeRoutes, int counter)
    {
        Stack<Node<TrainData>> s = new Stack<Node<TrainData>>();

        s.Push(GetRootStationNode(stationName));

        while (s.Count > 0)
        {
            var currentNode = s.Pop();
            if(!VisitedStation(currentNode.State.StationName, completeRoutes))
            {
                completeRoutes.Add(currentNode.State.StationName);
            }

            var allPossibleStation = GetAllPossibleNextStations(currentNode.State.StationName);

            foreach (var node in allPossibleStation)
            {
                if (counter > 0)
                {
                    if (!node.Visited)
                    {
                        node.Visited = true;
                        s.Push(node);
                        counter--;
                        GetRoutes(node.State.StationName, completeRoutes, counter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return completeRoutes;
    }
```

Here is the GetAllPossibleNextStations that retrieves all the child nodes of a particular station:

```
  public List<Node<TrainData>> GetAllPossibleNextStations(string input)
    {
        var possibleStations = new List<TrainData>();
        var NodeList = new List<Node<TrainData>>();

        var stationsMatchingInput = from f in dbList
                                    where f.StationName == input
                                    select f;

        foreach (var station in stationsMatchingInput)
        {
            var node = GetNextStation(station.PositionId);
            if (node != null && (node.State.Line == station.Line))
            {
                NodeList.Add(node);
            }
        }
```

I can't seem to get my head around this traversal business, so any suggestions would be great.